# Kubernetes pod cannot ping url or wget HTTPS site

Tags: kubernetes, https, dns, sonarqube

I'm trying to install SonarQube onto a bare-metal kubernetes cluster.

All is working except for when the software inside the pod tries to make a HTTPS request.

I've checked using wget (pod doesn't have curl & cannot use ping) & using the kubernetes DNS debugging guide, however whenever I make a call such as `wget https://google.com` I get the following error:

```
Connecting to google.com (192.168.1.179:443)
ssl_client: google.com: TLS connect failed
wget: error getting response: Connection reset by peer
command terminated with exit code 1
```

The IP address 192.168.1.179 is the address of another server on the host network.
The resolv.conf I have (ubuntu host) is:

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.0.0.1
```

I can't figure out why this is happening or how to fix it. DNS is *working* but not resolving HTTPS.

I'm using Calico, kubernetes dashboard, MetalLB, ingress-nginx & sonarqube

Edit:
After restarting the host the DNS servers successfully changed to 1.1.1.1.

However, now I'm presented with the following

```
Connecting to google.com (142.250.204.14:443)
ssl_client: google.com: TLS connect failed
wget: error getting response: Connection reset by peer
command terminated with exit code 1
```

Comment: Is it happening from any pod on this kubernetes cluster e.g. when you run a test pod with curl ?

Answer (score 1):

This error went away when I:

1. Disabled my firewall (ufw) and;
2. Restarted the machine for the DNS changes to take affect.